# How do I limit my raycast range?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I have these raycast commands and I want to put a range of 6 blocks on it. How can I do it?

```
execute as @e[dx=0, distance=0.1..] positioned ~-0.99 ~-0.99 ~-0.99 if entity @s[dx=0] run effect give @s instant_damage 1
execute positioned ^ ^ ^1 if block ~ ~ ~ air run function oscar:ray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to do it

Set a number equal to how many times the raycast can advance.

Decrease the number each time you advance the raycast 1 block forwards.

When you reach zero, stop advancing the raycast.

### In practice

Before you run the raycast function:

```
scoreboard objectives add count dummy
scoreboard players set #limit count 20
```

in your raycast function:

```
scoreboard players remove #limit count 1
```

---

at the beginning of this line:

```
execute positioned ^ ^ ^1 if block ~ ~ ~ air run function oscar:ray
```

add:

```
execute if score #limit count matches 1.. positioned ^ ^ ^1 if block ~ ~ ~ air run function oscar:ray
```

Comment: Good idea to have a main function who sets the `#limit` to 20 and call a secondary function, that shouldn't be called by anything but said main function. This guarantees it will work as it should.

Comment: hello, is this MP compatible?